# Proving $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n(1+nx^2)}$ converges uniformly.

Tags: calculus, limits, uniform-convergence

I want to prove the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n(1+nx^2)}$$
Converge uniformly in $[-1,1]$ and not in the rest of  $\mathbb{R}$.
I have solved similar problems to this using that a functions converges uniformly if and only if satisfies Cauchy condition, and then using the triangle inequality. In this case I can't do that since in the numerator I only have $x^n$. I have also tried to use the Weierstrass M-test without any results.

Comment: Did you mean to have the starting index as $n=1$?

Comment: @aleden Yes, sorry. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $|x|>1$ the series is divergent. For the interval $[-1,1]$, try again with Weierstrass M-test.

Note that for $0<r\leq |x|\leq 1$,
$$\left|\frac{x^n}{n(1+nx^2)}\right|\leq \frac{1}{n(1+nr^2)}\leq \frac{1}{r^2n^2}.$$
On the other hand, for $|x|\leq r<1$,
$$\left|\frac{x^n}{n(1+nx^2)}\right|\leq r^n.$$
Therefore, by taking $r=1/2$, we have that
$$\max_{x\in [-1,1]}\left|\frac{x^n}{n(1+nx^2)}\right|\leq \max\left(\frac{1}{2^n},\frac{4}{n^2}\right)=\frac{4}{n^2}.$$

Comment: I understand the first case, using the comparison test with $\frac{1}{r^2n^2}$ to $\frac{1}{n^2}$ I can see it converges and therefore the series uniformly converge. In the second case however I don't see how seeing tat $\left|\frac{x^n}{n(1+nx^2)}\right|\leq r^n$ proves anything since $r^n$ diverges. If we had $\left|\frac{x^n}{n(1+nx^2)}\right|\leq r^n$ then I could see $\left|\frac{x^n}{n(1+nx^2)}\right|$ diverges and therefore it does not converge uniformly. Thank you for your time

Comment: @JohnKeeper The series of $r^n$ is convergent for $r<1$. You can take $r=1/2$ in both cases.

Comment: My bad, I read $r>1$ instead of $r<1$. Anyway, I think I undersand it know, but could the problem be solved using only the first part of your answer? Seeing that $\left|\frac{x^n}{n(1+nx^2)}\right|\leq \frac{1}{n(1+nx^2)}\leq \frac{1}{x^2n^2}$, because $\frac{1}{x^2n^2}$ converges for any $r\in (-1,1)$?

Comment: No, because $x$ should be away from zero.